# My changes dissapeared after git reset --soft and git checkout. Where did they go?

Tags: git

I accidentally made a commit to the wrong branch (`dev`, instead of `feature/123`). I ran `git reset --soft HEAD^1` and checked out to `feature/123`, but now changes are nowhere to be found now. I expected them to be in my uncommited changelist. What happened?

Full git bash log:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        debug.log

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git reset --soft

$ git checkout feature/123
error: pathspec 'feature/123' did not match any file(s) known to git

$ git checkout -b feature/123
Switched to a new branch 'feature/123'

$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

$ git reset --soft HEAD^1

$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'feature/123'

$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        debug.log

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I find it kind of suspicious that the `git reset --soft HEAD^1` printed no output...

Comment: "*I find it kind of suspicious that the git reset --soft HEAD^1 printed no output*" Git commands are normally silent on success.

Comment: @Schwern: except for many of them printing progress messages if they take longer than about a half second, anyway. :-) You can turn this off with `--no-progress` although since most Git commands are so fast, it's often nice to have the progress messages for the slow ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes are in feature/123. `git checkout -` back to feature/123 wiped out your staging area because it matched the content of feature/123 and was redundant.

Here is a demonstration.

```
$ git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.git/
$ cd foo
$ touch this
$ git add this
$ git ci -a -m 'First'
[master (root-commit) 71d043e] First
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 this
$ echo 'foo' > this
$ git add this
$ git ci -a -m 'Second'
[master 5c0c064] Second
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

At this point I have two commits on master.

```
$ git co -b feature/123
Switched to a new branch 'feature/123'

$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'master'

$ git reset --soft HEAD^1
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   this
```

There's the change in the staging area.

```
$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'feature/123'
$ git status
On branch feature/123
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And it's gone because feature/123 already has that change. `git checkout` updates the staging area. The staging area matches HEAD and so is not preserved.

```
$ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Git did not retain the redundant staged changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, they were indeed commited in that branch. Does that mean they were there all along, even before the start of the posted bash log?

Comment: @MichalKurz Yes the commit existed in the repository because it's your original commit to dev. You then created feature/123 at the original dev commit. Branches in git are just labels pointing at a commit.

Answer (score 0):

Run  `git reflog`, or `git reflog dev`. You will find your initial commit on the `dev` branch there.

Answer (score 0):

You did a soft reset on dev, which moved you back one local commit, moving head and matching HEAD with index. Then you jumped back and forth a couple times between branches. Finally you called status again on dev, and HEAD still matched index. This is expected behavior.

If you had reset --mixed or --hard, you would have had to stash changes before you switched.